# I am passing a payload where it contains username and password i am masking them

Tags: java, mule, dataweave

I am passing a payload where it contains username and password i am masking them but i am trying to write a condition where if iam passing payload without username  and password it should skip mask condition and pass the payload can anyone help me out in this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in a way to detect if the payload contains credentials fields or not:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays
fun hasCredentials(o, credentialFields) = credentialFields every  (o[$]?)
var maskedFields=["username", "password"]
---
hasCredentials(payload, maskedFields)
```

If you want to do the masking in a simple way, mask the value only if the key name matches the ones for credentials. You can use mapObject() to do it:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun maskCredentials(p)= p mapObject ($$): if ($$ as String == "username" or $$ as String == "password") "xxxx" else $
---
maskCredentials(payload)
```

Input:

```json
{
    "name": "John",
    "address": "Some Street 21"
    "username": "john1",
    "password": "abc123"
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "name": "John",
  "address": "Some Street 21",
  "username": "xxxx",
  "password": "xxxx"
}
```

Comment: Updated with an condition only solution.